# How to login using OSCommerce customers database?

Tags: php, html, oscommerce

I have a website and i'm using OSCommerce as shoppig cart.
I need to make the user login to my site using OSCommerce email and password.

I know that there is a function

```
tep_validate_password($plain, $encrypted)
```

But when I tried this:

```
    require('market/catalog/includes/functions/password_funcs.php');

$x = tep_validate_password('0123272502','$P$Dhxb6Skb3xyDEsvyGfVbPnq62urXpb.');

if($x == true){echo 'true';}
else {echo 'false';}
```

it returns nothing at all.

Am I using it wrong?

Comment: check the function what is it return. I think this is return some thing else not true or false.

Comment: I tried echo tep_validate_password('0123272502','$P$Dhxb6Skb3xyDEsvyGfVbPnq62urXpb.'); but still not returning anything

Comment: here is the file that you are including check that https://github.com/osCommerce/oscommerce2/blob/master/catalog/admin/includes/functions/password_funcs.php         I think this is not including the proper way.

Comment: it is the same file contents in both admin and the one i use... but i tried it and still not working...

Comment: Is your file is outside of the oscommerce folder or it is inside?

Answer (score 0):

Your encrypted password for osCommerce 2.2 should be 19f1a88bdf871623e92cd12d29718d01:83
not $P$Dhxb6Skb3xyDEsvyGfVbPnq62urXpb.

If you are using osCommerce 2.3.x u have too also define DIR_WS_CLASSES , as it is used inside included function.